# Assistance identifying plant, white flowers, 6 lobed leaves, almost a foot high?

Tags: flowers

I am trying to identify the plant shown in the picture, the flowers are a little larger than an inch wide, with deep 6 lobed leaves, all plants are about a foot tall. Growing in North Eastern Ohio. If you need any additional observations let me know. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Like buttercup, but white...and larger flowers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an anemone. I am unsure of the variety ([according to Wikipedia there are about 150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone)). I have two. One that gets about 3 feet tall blooms in August (I have white, pink, and red). Another that is only about 9 inches and blooms in May/June (mine are only white and like photographed).

They are the ultimate weed (and I mean that in flattering terms) - carefree, pretty and require no special care. I just pull them from where I don't want them. They will be back. They do not spread aggressively (California poppies spread far more prolifically) and I would not call them noxious. The spent blossom will become a little bulb atop the stem. This bulb will turn into a fluffy mess (somewhat like dandelions) and seeds will go everywhere; so 'dead head' if you don't want them to spread (prolifically). Or don't dead head and pull them from where you don't want them.